# Integral expression for the modified Bessel function of second kind $K_\nu(x)$ for $\nu=1$.

Tags: bessel-functions

For a real variable $x$, and $x>0$, integral expression for the modified Bessel function of second kind of order $\nu$ is $$K_\nu(x)=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x\cosh t}\cosh(\nu t)dt.$$ Let us consider the case $\nu=1$ such that $$K_1(x)=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x\cosh t}\cosh(t)dt.$$ Next, we make a change of variable: $$y=x\cosh(t)\Rightarrow dy=x\sinh(t) dt$$ so that the expression for $K_1(x)$ reduces to $$K_1(x)=x^{-1}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}ye^{-y}(y^2-x^2)^{-1/2}dy.$$

But this does not agree with the expression in Eq.($11.69$) given [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=6QXqlCHLjJkC&pg=PA401&lpg=PA401&dq=are%20the%20modified%20Bessel%20functions%20(Kolb%20and%20Turner,%201990).%20Concentrating&source=bl&ots=Bpa-2c1j6N&sig=ACfU3U03LQBedFazh1tgQ5Y21fXsKlnU-g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjWierUiv3kAhUY6nMBHXN9ClYQ6AEwAHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=are%20the%20modified%20Bessel%20functions%20(Kolb%20and%20Turner%2C%201990).%20Concentrating&f=false). In this expression $z$ is a real variable with $z\geq 0$, and is same as $x$ in my notation. What is the error I have made?

Answer (score 1):

The lower limit of your (last) integral must be $x$. To get $(11.69)$ from it, just integrate by parts: $$xK_1(x)=\left.e^{-y}\sqrt{y^2-x^2}\right|_{y=x}^{y=\infty}-\int_x^{\infty}(-e^{-y})\sqrt{y^2-x^2}\,dy=\ldots$$